# Scala java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type A is not supported

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

This code is running fine in various cases but intermittently throwing some wired exceptions including NullPointer exception.
I have printed down the output even size and type class of each element, No element is even null or Nill but still getting the exceptions

I have also tried everything in test cases but still not able to find the exact point when these exceptions are thrown

```
case class SimpleCaseClass(str1: String, long1: Long, str2: String,
                           list1: List[String], list2: List[String],
                           list3: List[Long], list4: List[String],
                           list5: List[String],
                           list6: List[String], mapOfString: Map[String, String])

object oo{
  import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema
  import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders

  val caseClassOutput: SimpleCaseClass =
    SimpleCaseClass("Accept", 1, "my_id", List(), Nil, List(), List(), List(), List(), Map())
  val caseClassOutputArray = caseClassOutput.productIterator.toSeq.toArray
  println(caseClassOutputArray)
  val aa = new GenericRowWithSchema(caseClassOutputArray, Encoders.product[SimpleCaseClass].schema)
}
```

ExceptionTrace NullPointer

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.localTypeOf(ScalaReflection.scala:941)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.localTypeOf(ScalaReflection.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:584)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:468)
    at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeConstraints$UndoLog.undo(TypeConstraints.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor(ScalaReflection.scala:468)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.serializerFor(ScalaReflection.scala:457)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder$.apply(ExpressionEncoder.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders$.product(Encoders.scala:275)
```

Another exception

```
Exception while creating row java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type A is not supported
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:809)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:740)
    at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeConstraints$UndoLog.undo(TypeConstraints.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:739)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:761)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:740)
    at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeConstraints$UndoLog.undo(TypeConstraints.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:739)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$deserializerFor$1.getPath$1(ScalaReflection.scala:196)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$deserializerFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:368)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$deserializerFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:173)
    at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeConstraints$UndoLog.undo(TypeConstraints.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$deserializerFor(ScalaReflection.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$deserializerFor$1$$anonfun$7.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:414)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$deserializerFor$1$$anonfun$7.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:403)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:296)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$deserializerFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:403)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$deserializerFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:173)
    at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeConstraints$UndoLog.undo(TypeConstraints.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$deserializerFor(ScalaReflection.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.deserializerFor(ScalaReflection.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder$.apply(ExpressionEncoder.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders$.product(Encoders.scala:275)
```

On printing size and type and response

```
(first,19,my_id,List(),List(),List(),List(),List(),List(),Map())
scala.collection.immutable.List[java.lang.String]
scala.collection.immutable.List[java.lang.String]
scala.collection.immutable.List[Long]
scala.collection.immutable.List[java.lang.String]
scala.collection.immutable.List[java.lang.String]
scala.collection.immutable.List[java.lang.String]
scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String, java.lang.String]
List()
List()
List()
List()
List()
List()
Map()
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

Comment: what is `object oo`?

Comment: ``oo`` is the sample object code from a large code

Answer (score 1):

This problem got resolved by instead of using  **GenericRowWithSchema** created simple row and assign schema manually later if required

```
Row.fromSeq(SimpleCaseClass.productIterator.toList)
```